# Updating a Table with Jquery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have quite a large page with a lot of content, one part of which is a table of prices against dates. Typically the table looks like this:
[image]

The "Previous" and "Next" links and the datepicker enable the user to show a different range of dates in the table. However using simple html forms and php/mysql, the whole page refreshes every time and that looks pretty messy. I want to use jQuery and Ajax to refresh just the table.

To that end I have put the table in a separate file using PHP include(). That separate file called calendar_inner.php uses a variable called $startdate to do the necessary mysql queries to get all the data for the table. Now I just need to understand how to feed the included file with a new value of $startdate and then refresh that file. This is where I am groping in the dark with jQuery.

Starting with just the datepicker, I have started to write the jQuery script, but unsurprisingly it doesn't work.

```
$('#StartDateCal').on('submit', function(g) { 
    g.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    var startdate = $("#StartDate").val();
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'calendar_inner.php',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

Please be gentle with me. My occasional success with jQuery has been limited to occasions when I have been able to copy someone else's piece of code virtually verbatim. Thanks.

EDIT
I've modified my script based on the advice from Raslett but I haven't reached the solution yet.

```
$('#StartDateCal').on('submit', function(g) { 
    g.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'calendar_inner.php',
        data: $('#StartDateCal').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $('#getresult').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Now the full page doesn't refresh, only the calendar_inner.php file, so that's a little success. I think the issue now is what to do with the result. Using the code above and placing

```
<div id="getresult"></div>
```

at the start of calendar_inner.php inserts my 404 Error page into the overall page. Changing html(result) to text(result) writes the whole code of the 404 Error page into the same space. What I don't know is what is being generated by the script that causes the server to invoke the 404 Error page.

SECOND EDIT
I got rid of the 404 Error. I was calling the url wrong. Now that is corrected, I am getting closer but the remaining stuff to do is pretty mysterious. The script now writes the first row of the table twice: once with a start date of 1 Jan and the second time with the original start date. So now all I have to do is:
1. Persuade the first version of the table row to use the new start date
2. Stop the second version of the table row from showing
3. Pass the start date to the next part of the table where the prices are calculated and written
Phew! Not easy.

THIRD EDIT
As Rasclatt said, the jQuery is now working and I just need to sort out the calendar_inner.php file. For simplicity, I'm just putting the first few lines below. The key variable is $startdate, which then drives everything else. I need the jQuery to change the value of $startdate.

FOURTH EDIT
Updated the code of calendar_inner.php and showed more of it. See below.

```
<div id="getresult"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//Submit change of date in price tab without refreshing page
$('#StartDateCal').on('submit', function(g) { 
        g.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/includes/calendar_inner.php',
            data: $('#StartDateCal').serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result),
                $('#getresult').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['StartDate']) && !empty($_POST['StartDate'])) {
            $startdate  =   htmlentities($_POST['StartDate'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $firstdate  =   date('Y-m-d',$startdate);
            $lastdate   =   date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+11 days',strtotime($firstdate)));

            // database insertion of above variables
        }else{
            $firstdate = date('Y-m-d',$startdate);
$lastdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+11 days',strtotime($firstdate)));
        }

//Select database
require_once('../Connections/MySQL.php');
mysql_select_db($database_MySQL, $MySQL);
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

// Create a temporary table
$query_temptable = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable (dt DATE NOT NULL)";
$result = mysql_query($query_temptable, $MySQL) or die(mysql_error());

//Now loop through the date range and fill the temporary table
$thisdate = $firstdate;
while (strtotime($thisdate) <= strtotime($lastdate)){
$query_insertdate = "INSERT INTO temptable (dt) VALUES ('$thisdate')";
$result2 = mysql_query($query_insertdate, $MySQL) or die(mysql_error());
$thisdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($thisdate)));
}

// MySQL query to get price_id (or blank) for all dates in range
$query_tariff = "SELECT temptable.dt, lh_dates.tariff_id FROM temptable LEFT JOIN lh_dates ON temptable.dt = lh_dates.dt AND hid = '$hid'";
$tariff = mysql_query($query_tariff, $MySQL) or die(mysql_error());

// Create array of tariff_ids
$i = 0;
$tariff_id_list = array();
while ($row_tariff = mysql_fetch_assoc($tariff)) {
$tariff_id_list[$i] = $row_tariff['tariff_id'];
$date_list[$i] = $row_tariff['dt'];
$i++;
}
$tariff_id_unique = array_unique($tariff_id_list);

// Drop the temporary table
$query_droptable = "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temptable";
$result3 = mysql_query($query_droptable, $MySQL) or die(mysql_error());

//Here we start building the pseudo-table using divs 
echo "<div class='calendar'>";
// Dates row
echo "<div class='toprow'>"; 
echo "<div class='cal_firstcol'>&nbsp;</div>";
$i = 0;
$thisdate=strtotime($firstdate);
while ($i++ < 12) {
$day_week = date('D', $thisdate); 
$day_num = date('j', $thisdate);
$month_name = strtoupper(date('M', $thisdate));
echo "<div class='cal_dates'>";
echo $day_week."<br><span class='cal_day'>".$day_num."</span><br>".$month_name;
$thisdate = $thisdate+86400;
echo "</div>"; 
}
echo "<div class='clear'></div></div>";

// Room rows
//MySQL query to get rooms
$query_room = "SELECT room_id, roomtype, normalocc, singleocc, extrabed, childbed, cot FROM lh_rooms WHERE hid = '$hid' ORDER BY orderr ASC";
$room = mysql_query($query_room, $MySQL) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_room = mysql_fetch_assoc($room)) {
foreach ($tariff_id_unique as $value) {
$tariff_id = $value;
$room_id = $row_room['room_id'];
$query_price = "SELECT * FROM lh_prices WHERE tariff_id = '$tariff_id' AND room_id = '$room_id'";
$price = mysql_query($query_price, $MySQL) or die(mysql_error());
$row_price[$value] = mysql_fetch_assoc($price);
}

echo "<div class='row'>"; 
echo "<div class='cal_firstcol'>".$row_room['roomtype']."</div>";
$thisdate = $firstdate;
$i=0;
while (strtotime($thisdate) <= strtotime($lastdate)){
$thisday = strtolower(date('D',strtotime($thisdate)));
echo "<div class='cal_pricecol'>";
if (in_array($thisday, $we_rates)) {
echo $row_price[$tariff_id_list[$i]]['price_we_std'];   
}else{
echo $row_price[$tariff_id_list[$i]]['price_wd_std'];
}
echo "</div>";
$i++;
$thisdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day',strtotime($thisdate)));
}
echo "</div>";

if (($row_room['extrabed']>=1)||($row_room['childbed']>=1)) {
echo "<div class='row hiddenrow' style='display:none'>"; 
echo "<div class='cal_firstcol'>Child Extra Bed</div>";
$thisdate = $firstdate;
$i=0;
while (strtotime($thisdate) <= strtotime($lastdate)){
$thisday = strtolower(date('D',strtotime($thisdate)));
echo "<div class='cal_pricecol'>";
echo $row_price[$tariff_id_list[$i]]['price_eb_c']; 
echo "</div>";
$i++;
$thisdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day',strtotime($thisdate)));
}
echo "<div class='clear'></div></div>";
}

}

echo "</div>"; 
?>
```

FIFTH EDIT (!)
In reply to Rasclatt, this is what the table looks like after the script has run.
[image]
The datepicker, Previous, the checkbox and Next are all in the parent page. The first row of dates starting 30 Sep are the result of the script and the second row of dates are coded into calendar_inner.php. Moving

```
<div id="getresult"></div>
```

further down the page moves the first row of dates accordingly.
The code of the form for the datepicker is

```
<form id="StartDateCal">
<input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid" value="<?php echo $hid ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" id="lang" value="<?php echo $$ln ?>">
From <input name="StartDate" id="StartDate" class="datebox" size="10" value="<?php echo date('j M Y', $startdate) ?>" type="date"> 
<input name="submit" class="button" id="CalSubmitBtn" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Also, the only reason I dropped `<div id="getresult"></div>` in the code is to show you feedback. You can point the feedback to any container.

Comment: Thanks Rasclatt. I'll put calendar_inner.php in now.

Comment: Initially $startdate is set to "today" in the parent file. Then the form sends a new value via jQuery which needs to be passed into $startdate.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the many good jQUery based table data plugins that kind of deal with the client side portion of this for you?

Comment: Mike Brant. No, I hadn't considered plugins. I've just had a look at some but I didn't see any that do what I want. Perhaps some of the more comprehensive ones do, but it would take time to find out, more time to set ip all up, and then I would end up with a lot of code that wasn't being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should load the form, then script which will autoload your table via AJAX into the `<div id="get result"></div>` container. On submission of the form, it should load into the same spot overwriting the table. So, just to clarify, you wouldn't run any php to build the table on the original load page. All you would run php for is to calculate the `$hid`, `$$ln`, and `$startdate`. Your `calendar_inner.php` would only contain the calendar code, and the load page would only contain the form and jQuery.

As an option, I added a preference to the `CheckDates(FetchResults)` where `FetchResults` is the name of the container. Just incase you want to load it to a different container name you can.

```
<form id="StartDateCal">
<input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid" value="<?php echo $hid ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" id="lang" value="<?php echo $$ln ?>">
From <input name="StartDate" id="StartDate" class="datebox" size="10" value="<?php echo date('j M Y', $startdate) ?>" type="date"> 
<input name="submit" class="button" id="CalSubmitBtn" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="getresult"></div>
<script>
    function CheckDates(FetchResults)
        {
             $.ajax ({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/includes/calendar_inner.php',
                data: $("#StartDateCal").serialize(),
                success: function(result) {
                 $("#"+FetchResults).html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Auto load ajax
        CheckDates('getresult');
        // On submit load ajax
        $('#StartDateCal').submit(function() {
            // Add a loader image or text so you know it's refreshing
            $('#getresult').html("Loading...");
            // Run table loader
            CheckDates('getresult');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, the form is id="StarteDateCal". I hadn't used serialize as I thought it wasn't necessary when I was passing only one variable. However there was a little finger-error in my code because "data" should have been "startdate". I've made some progress using your suggested code but not there yet. See my EDIT of the original post for more info.

Comment: No it's not literally saying "today". Perhaps I should have said it is equal to "time()".
I see where you are coming from with your calendar_inner.php code but it's not quite there yet. I realised that the datepicker <input> had a name and id of StartDate so I changed your $_POST variable to suit. However when I use the datepicker to change startdate I am still getting two date rows: the first one starts from 1 Jan and the second one starts from 1 Oct (today). I'll do another edit of my original question with more of the calendar_inner.php code.

Comment: Since the fourth edit up above, I've been fiddling around to try to understand what's happening. I've now found from console.log that (result) contains the div, the script and the first row of the table with the new dates. That explains why I get two rows of dates: first the new one and then the old ones. How can I just get a new value for $startdate in (result)?

Comment: Rasclatt, I just added a visual of the table as it looks after running the script, and also the code of the form. (I wasn't sure which you wanted to see. I really appreciate your patience in sticking with me on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62357/discussion-between-trapezeartist-and-rasclatt).

Comment: Let me know if this solution works. It should...(famous last words).

Comment: Also, I added a loader spot. It will replace the table with "Loading..." or any image/text you want. You can also remove it if you want, I just put it there so know that it's possible and depending on how different the tables are, it may not look as if it's changed when the submission is clicked, when in fact it has, so the loader will clear that table then the ajax will load so the user will know that it did something. May or may not be useful.

Comment: Hmz, if you have a function called on page load which submits a form, the form data is empty

Comment: Well it shouldn't be empty because you should have loaded the three variable into it first at page load `$hid`, `$$ln`, and `$startdate`? Then when you change the start date it should change the ajax on it.  Here is an example....[demo](http://www.mxicorp.com/client_assets/workboard.php). It would load the page, then load into the spot your form. Then on submit, it would refresh the same spot

Comment: Maybe the question I should ask is how you you get those 3 variables initially into your `datepicker` form? I assumed you have `loadpage.php` (named however it's named) that loads the form with presets first and this `loadpage.php` then calls the ajax page at load or on submission...